# Item & total rounding is NULL when I'm creating new order by Admin API in testenv

Tags: php, shopware, shopware6

I'm creating new **order** via **Admin API**. It works on every environment except **testenv**.

There order is created, but **item_rounding** and **total_rounding** is **NULL** in the DB. So in the admin panel I can't see the order details, as Vue throws an error due to lack of rounding information.

[2 orders, first is created by Admin API, second is how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxOai.png)

I checked it with local environment and there it works perfectly fine. I provided these same data and got these same empty 204 result. It's not working only on this env https://github.com/shopwareLabs/testenv-platform

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a misunderstanding. `shopwareLabs/testenv-platform` is meant to be used for internal tests of plugins submitted to the community store of Shopware.

As stated in the description of the repository:

> This environment is in use **internally** for testing store plugins.

So I wouldn't worry about this abnormal behavior and switch to a different environment for testing purposes.